# How do I configure Spring STS to run Selenium test classes?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, selenium, junit

I'm using Spring STS (3.7) to develop an MVC application. I'm attempting to run a simple Selenium test using an example I've read in a book. I'm receiving a 'ClassNotFoundException' when I run the JUnit test. What's odd is that class that's not found is the test class itself: 'UIHomeTest'. I've verified that I have JUnit, Hamcrest and Selenium on the classpath. I've tried adding the JUnit library to the run configuration. Here is the code for the test class:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
```

public class UIHomeTest {

```
private WebDriver browser;


private static final String HOME_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}


@Test
public void testHomePage()
{

    browser.get(HOME_URL);

    assertEquals("Home", browser.findElement(By.id("title")).getAttribute("value"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception
{
    browser.close();
}

}
```

Here is the error:

```
Class not found org.test.ui.UIHomeTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.test.ui.UIHomeTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I've been able to run a non-Selenium JUnit test class inside of Spring STS before. Can anyone help me properly configure Spring STS to run Selenium test classes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On observing the imports and selenium code i found there are few not required imports used like import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium; import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase; and also not used or initiated driver object. below is the complete code which works fine for me.

com.tesngtraining; is my package. If you are downloaded java specific selenium jars then please include all jars which are in different folders in build path or download standalone selenium jar file and give it in build path.

```
 package com.tesngtraining;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestingJunit {

private WebDriver browser;


private static final String HOME_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    browser = new FirefoxDriver();

}


@Test
public void testHomePage()
{

    browser.get(HOME_URL);

    assertEquals("Home", browser.findElement(By.id("title")).getAttribute("value"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception
{
    browser.close();
}

}
```

Thank you,
Murali

Comment: Thanks for response. I removed the unused imports but the problem persists. I use Gradle for my dependency management and consequently have `testCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.+'` in my build file. How are you running the test class inside Spring STS? I right-click on the class in Package Explorer and select Run As > JUnit Test.from the context menu.

Comment: Hi, i execute in normal eclipse not in STS.. i have to try once in eclipse STS

Comment: Hi. Would you mind sharing a simple working Eclipse example via GitHub/Gist or BitBucket? It would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IF it's a spring boot application u need to add the annnotation @springbootTest above your class , also the webdriver need to be injected by @autowired

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).